# Information given by users in their profiles

Tags: support

I was editing my profile when I saw there was a place where I can give my email, full name and my date of birth. There on the top it was written "Private information (not shown publicly)". It is my private information why the sites wants all this? What site will do with it? On the top of the space given to write the date of birth it was written "(only used for displaying age)". If all these information will not be displayed then why "(only used for displaying age)" was written?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165642/215040